# We know the asymptotic density of primes. What about the asymptotic density of numbers with n prime factors?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

Question in title. When I say n prime factors, I don't mean n distinct prime factors.

Comment: The generalized prime number theorem is set out in this question. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168307/generalized-pnt-in-limit-as-numbers-get-large.